# Cycle error occurs when running 'npm start'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

I am trying to run a node application locally on my computer. I receive the following error when I run `npm start` on my command line:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-express@1.0.0 start: `node index`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-express@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "node-express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node Express Examples",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index"
  },
  "author": "Shilpa Kancharla",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  }
}
```

And here is my `index.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;

const app = express();

const morgan = require('morgan');
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const dishRouter = require('./routes/dishRouter');
const promoRouter = require('./require/promoRouter');
const leaderRouter = require('./require/leaderRouter');
app.use('/dishes', dishRouter);
app.use('/promotions', promoRouter);
app.use('/leaders', leaderRouter);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.headers);
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.end('<html><body><h1>This is an Express Server </h1></body></html>');
});

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

I have tried installing and uninstalling the node modules, changing the name of the `start` to `node index.js` instead of `node index` but have had no such luck.

Comment: You're missing `express` and `http` package, try to run `npm install express && npm install http`, then `npm start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node Express Examples",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "Shilpa Kancharla",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

and now run and update node module by running following command

```
npm i or npm install
```

you can now start by running the following command

```
npm start
```